# SSIS package not deleting AS400 records

Tags: ssis, ibm-midrange

I have an SSIS package which downloads data from `AS400` to SQL Server.
This is working fine but:

The pre-final task (`Execute SQL task`) is to delete the downloaded records from `AS400`.

The query is simple:

```
DELETE FROM (TABLE_NAME)
```

I am pretty sure that this task is being hit because a Send Email task after this is working.

The issue is occurring on one server only. And I am unable to figure out why.
The entire setup is the same for all servers.

Comment: If your precedent constraints are set up correctly and you're simply deleting everything from the table (use TRUNCATE TABLE instead) then you may want to rethink your logic. Is there any possibility with your current pattern that data can be reinserted after the table is truncated?

Comment: Older versions of DB2 for i didn't support truncate table.  But DB2 for i is  also smart enough to do the equivalent of a truncate table when you `delete` all rows.

Answer (score 3):

Try to track down the joblog of the job servicing the request.  If there are errors that are being passed along by SSIS, you'll see them there.

One issue I've seen, especially with people that still call the system AS/400, is that the tables aren't being journaled; which means that when SSIS attempts to delete the rows under commitment control, it will fail with an error.